# How does the negative form of である get to be ではない?

Tags: grammar, etymology

http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/formal#part3 doesn't explain the reason clearly.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out that は insertion happens in other constructions as well, eg. XXして**は**いけない or 飲んで**は**いない or 離したく**は**ない or 変わり**は**しない.

Comment: Vaguely related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12644/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"ではない" is the negation of the assertion

> **Positive:** 「学生である」->「学生だ」("だ" is assertive sentence) ---> OK
>   **Negative:** 「学生でない」->「学生でないだ」「学生だでない」---> NG
>   alternate 「[学生(だ)]{assertive} <は> [ない]{Negative}」 >>>「学生ではない」 ---> OK

"Assertion" has the meaning of enhancement(or Emphasis) for the Subject.
"ではない" provides further emphasis than "でない". (the Subject is "彼が学生でないこと")

Note:

> 「彼は*学生である*」 ---> OK (Simple Positive and Simple Assertion)
>   「彼は*学生でない*」---> OK (Simple Negative)
>   「彼は*学生ではある*」 ---> OK (Positive affirmation of the Assertion)
>   「彼は*学生ではない*」 ---> OK (Negation of the Assertion)

Examples:

> 「彼は確かに*学生である*」
>   「彼が*学生でない*ことは確かだ」
>   「彼は働いていないが、*学生ではある*」
>   「彼は勉強をしているが、*学生ではない*」

Comment: You say でない is not ok, and you say it is ok again.
I'm confused.

Comment: @Minsky Sorry! 「学生でない」is OK. 「学生でないだ」or 「学生だでない」 is NG.

Answer (score 8):

Without fear, I am going to state that both 「でない」 and 「ではない」 are "correct" negative forms of 「である」.  Both are in wide use in our time.

That is, however, ***not*** to say that there exists a great amount of interchangeability between 「でない」 and 「ではない」.

> 「ではない」 is used most often in main clauses while 「でない」 is generally used in subordinate clauses.

***Main Clause: "This is not pizza."***

> 「これはピザ**ではない**。」 sounds more than natural and correct.
>
> 「これはピザ**でない**。」 sounds very unnatural and inappropriate.  Most native speakers would correct you right away if you said this.

***Subordinate Clause: "You cannot be a model if you are not pretty."***

> 「きれい**でない**と、モデルにはなれない。」 sounds perfectly natural and "correct".
>
> 「きれい**ではない**と、モデルにはなれない。」 sounds just wrong and unnatural.